# Combining multiple condition in single case statement

Tags: exact-online, invantive-sql, invantive-control, invantive-query-tool

Does Invantive SQL support multiple condition in a single case statement? I the  statement below, I did not get any results. Tried the same statement with only 1 condition (no cascade), this retrieved the expected result.

```
   select prj.code
   ,      prj.startdate
   ,      prj.enddate
   from   exactonlinerest..projects prj
   where  prj.code between $P{P_PROJECT_FROM} and $P{P_PROJECT_TO}
   and    case
   /*       when (prj.enddate is null or prj.enddate >= sysdate)
          then 'Y'   
          when (prj.enddate is not null and prj.enddate <= sysdate)
          then 'N'   */
          when prj.startdate <= sysdate  
          then 'B'  
          end 
          = $P{P_PROJECT_ACTIVE_FROM}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you where clause is not correctly formulated. With Exact Online, a project either has:

- option 1: no end date,
- option 2: an end date in the past
- option 3: or an end date in the future

The first part of the `case` handles option 1 and option 3. The second part handles option 2. So there is never an outcome of `'B'` in the case.

To analyze such problems, I recommend include the `case` in the select clause and removing the filter. That gives you a view of the possible outcomes.

Example:

```
use 868056,102673

select prj.division
,      prj.code
,      prj.startdate
,      prj.enddate
,      case
       when prj.enddate is null or prj.enddate >= sysdate
       then 'Y'   
       when prj.enddate is not null and prj.enddate <= sysdate
       then 'N'   
       when prj.startdate <= sysdate  
       then 'B'  
       end 
       indicator
from   exactonlinerest..projects prj   
where  prj.code between $P{P_PROJECT_FROM} and $P{P_PROJECT_TO}
```